# How to fix 'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_get_driver_instance" ' linker error

Tags: c++, mysql, xcode, macos, linker

Im trying to build a simple project with c++ and mysql (mysql-connector-c++).
And after few hours of work i managed to solve a problem with linking the boost lib and the mysql-connector-c++ lib with my project in Xcode.

Solve it by adding those paths to my Xcode project:
(in headers and library search paths, on project build settings)

[headers and library search paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsTUR.png)

Now when i try to make a simple connection to my database using mysql example as follow :

```
void DataBase::connectToDataBase() {

    driver =  get_driver_instance();
    setConectionProperties();

    try {
        connection = driver->connect(*properties);
        connection->setSchema(DATABASE);
    }catch (SQLException &e) {
        cout << e.what();
    }
    this->~DataBase();
    exit(1);
}
```

[My complete code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJO8f.png)

I get the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_get_driver_instance", referenced from:
>         DataBase::connectToDataBase() in DataBase.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Full error log with linker command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VsxT.png)

I don't have much understanding in linker errors, and in how to fix them.
I googled this problem and saw that is a very common one, but didn't manage to understand or fix it.

If you have any suggestion i will be happy to hear.

**Some necessary details:**
Im working on a MacBook Air High Sierra version 10.13.6
Installed 'boost' and 'mysql-connector-c++' via Homebrew.
Im using Xcode Version 10.1

- if some details are missing please let me know and ill add them right away.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: where is get_driver_instance() defined?

Comment: @nivpeled in driver.h from  'mysql-connector-c++' lib.
like this :    
extern "C"      
{     
 CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC sql::Driver * get_driver_instance();    
}

outside the class Driver

Comment: ok and what is your linker command line?

Comment: @nivpeled is that what you mean by linker command line:
[link](https://ibb.co/DVXhbFK) (photo from Xcode)

Comment: yes. You must tell the linker to link with the lib -lmysqlcppconn8). See more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-cpp/8.0/usage.html

Comment: @nivpeled i add -lmysqlcppconn (without the '8') and its worked!!
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution for my problem was :**

adding to the 'Other Linker Flags' the flag : "-lmysqlcppconn"

('Other Linker Flags' can be found in 'Linking' in project Build Settings)

[The solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNfgH.png)

- Many thanks for @nivpeled